# Express Router CRUD Update and Delete data

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have issues to implement CRUD to my webapp, The data are stored in the mongoDB at the cloud successfully using a FORM,also managed to display the data for the user. But my issue is to update the inserted data also to delete them.
Please take a look my codes. When I click on Update / Delete links I get Cannot GET /delete/ or Cannot GET /Update/.
I would appreciate If anyone can help me out.

> server.js

```
    app.get("/guestbook", function(req,res){

         // res.render("pages/guestbook",{
        db.collection('newmessage').find().toArray(function (err, result)  {
      if (err) return console.log(err)
      res.render('pages/guestbook', {newmessage: result});

    });

          });
//Form to insert Guest book messages
      app.get("/newmessage", function(req,res){
          res.sendFile(__dirname  + "/pages/newmessage");

          res.render("pages/newmessage",{
              add_newMessage:"Add Your info & message!"
          });

      });
//Accepts users inputs and saves to mongoDB
      app.post("/newmessage" , function(req,res){
        var guestMessage = {
          username:req.body.username,
          country:req.body.country,
          message:req.body.message,
          date:req.body.date
        };
        //assert.equal(null, err);
  db.collection('newmessage').insertOne(guestMessage, function(err, result) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      console.log('Message saved to database');
      res.redirect('/guestbook');
    });

      });
  app.post("/update/:id", function (req,res){
    var guestMessage = {
          username:req.body.username,
          country:req.body.country,
          message:req.body.message,
          date:req.body.date
        };
        var Gid = req.params.id;

    db.collection('newmessage').findById(Gid, {$set: guestMessage}, function(err, result) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      result.save(function (err,result) {
       console.log('Message Updated');
          res.redirect('/guestbook');
      })


    });


      });

  app.get("/delete/: id" , function (req, res) {
     var Gid = req.params.id.toString();

     db.collection('newmessage').findById( Gid, function(err, result) {
  result.remove(function (err, result) {
      res.redirect('/guestbook');
  });


    });

});
```

> newmessage.ejs

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <% include ../partials/head %>
</head>

<body class="container">

    <header>
        <% include ../partials/header %>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="jumbotron">

        <form class="messageForm" method="post" action="/newmessage">
            <fieldset>
            <legend><%= add_newMessage %></legend>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name ="username" placeholder="Enter Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="country">Country:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="country"name="country" placeholder="Enter country">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="message">Message:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="message" name= "message" placeholder="Enter message">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="date">Date:</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date"name="date" placeholder="Enter date">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>


    </fieldset>

</form>

        </div>
    </main>

    <footer>
<% include ../partials/footer %>
</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

> guestbook.ejs

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <% include  ../partials/head %>
</head>

<body class="container">

    <header>
        <% include  ../partials/header  %>


    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="jumbotron">

           <table  border = "1">
               <tr>

                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Message</th>
                     <th>Date</th>
                       <th>Edit</th>
                       <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>

            <% for(var i=0; i<newmessage.length; i++) {%>


                <tr>

                    <td class="userInput"><%= newmessage[i].username %></td>
                    <td class="userInput"><%= newmessage[i].country %></td>
                    <td class="userInput"><%= newmessage[i].message %></td>
                    <td class="userInput"><%= newmessage[i].date %></td>
                    <td class="userInput"><a href="/update/<%= newmessage._id %>">Update</a></td>
                    <td class="userInput"><a href="/delete/<%= newmessage._id %>">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>


            <%} %>
            </table>


</div>
    </main>

     <footer>
<%  include  ../partials/footer  %>
</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

[Sample OutPut/image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoiXa.png)

Answer (score 2):

For update and delete use

```
app.put('/your_route/:id',function(e,r){});
app.delete('/your_route/:id',function(e,r){});
```

you should not request app.get for create,update or delete operation.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, as the previous answer says, updating entries in a database traditionally involves using the HTTP `PUT` method, as seen [on MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT), and deleting an entity in a database traditionally involves using the HTTP `DELETE` method, as seen [on MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE). That being said, you would want to utilize these methods in your Express app by declaring `app.put` and `app.delete` as the previous answer shows.

Now the problem with using these methods is that these methods don't work very well with HTML pages, for some reason that I can't remember right now. So, developers have been forced to come up with clever ways to use these methods, the simplest of which is just specifying the method in the query string.

To use this with Express, you would need some middleware such as [method-override](https://www.npmjs.com/package/method-override) that tells your app how you're going to be declaring the HTTP method, that way Express knows to utilize the routes you define as `app.put` or whatever. In order to use this specific package, you would need to make these update and delete buttons be forms with a POST method, and in the action, use a query parameter to specify the method. For example, in your server.js:

```
// ...
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
// ...
const app = express();
// ...
app.use(methodOverride('_method');
```

Then, to use for the update button, you'd need to change the button from being an `a` tag to being a `form` as follows:

```
<form method="POST" action="/update?_method=PUT">
  // inputs to change the data go here
  <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

This way, when the user clicks the button, Express parses the POST request as a PUT request, and calls the proper middlewares. Just remember to put the `app.use(methodOverride('_method'))` line before the declaration of all your routes.

As a more direct answer to your question, the reason why you're getting the "Cannot GET /update" is because `a` tags are, by definition, HTML elements that make GET requests only, and you didn't define an Express route for GET requests to '/update'. You could, of course, ignore the method override stuff and just switch out those two `a` tags for standard `form` elements, using a POST method (since I see that thats how you defined the routes in your server.js), however this is far from best practice and should be avoided.